# Object manipulation within arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, coffeescript, framerjs

I'm building a function that's supposed to let a layer work like an on and off switch, dropping every layer that is higher than it in the array and then, when clicked again, return all the layers to their original position. I managed to make it target the right layers when turning it on, but I can't get it turn off (close back)
Can someone please point me in the right direction to get this code to work.
Thank you.

```
layers=[]
layerNames=[]
indexL=0

for i in [0...5]
 layer=layers[i]=new Layer
    y:230*i

 do (layers,i)->
     clickD=false
     layers[i].onClick ->
         for l,index in layers
            if @.index<l.index
                layers[index].animate
                    properties:
                        y:230*index+300
                clickD=true
            else if @.index<l.index and clickD!=false
                layers[index].animate
                    properties:
                        y:230*index
            else
                layers[index].animate
                    properties:
                        y:230*index
```

Framer link:https://framer.cloud/xcxXg/

Comment: Update: I have edited this and used stateCycle, which seemed to have solved the problem of layers not closing back in, but now if I click a layer above the active layer, @layer goes mental.

Comment: layers=[]
layerNames=[]
indexL=0

for i in [0...5]
 layer=layers[i]=new Layer
  y:230*i
 layers[i].states.add
  on:
   y:228*i+300
  off:
   y:228*i
 do (layers,i)->
  clickD=false
  layers[i].onClick ->
   for l,index in layers
    if @.id>=l.id
     layers[index].states.switch("off")
     clickD=layers[i].states.current.name
     print clickD

    else 
     layers[index].stateCycle("on","off")
     clickD=layers[i].states.current.name
     print clickD